# My global Components are not available

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I am new to vuex so i might have only a really dumb mistake.
I am trying to make a reactive Router, for that i used the store from vuex and since i have multiple Components i used a selfwritten Plugin to make them all global. My problem is that the store, where all the routes are saved,and all other components dont have access to the components i set global. I get the following Errormessage:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Home is not defined

my Plugin to make the components global
componentPlugin.js:

```
import List from "./components/List.vue";
import MainMenu from "./components/MainMenu.vue";
import Test from "./views/Test.vue";
import About from "./views/About.vue";
import Menu from "./views/Menu.vue";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.component("List", List);
    Vue.component("MainMenu", MainMenu);
    Vue.component("Test", Test);
    Vue.component("About", About);
    Vue.component("Menu", Menu);
    Vue.component("Home", Home);
  }
};
```

my store.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    projects: [{ id: 0, title: "Create new Project", compRate: 0 }],
    globalid: 1,
    projectname: "",
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/home",
        name: "home",
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        name: "about",
        component: About
      },
      {
        path: "/menu",
        name: "menu",
        component: Menu
      }
    ],
    reloaded: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    newProject: (state, project) => {
      state.projects.push({
        id: project.id,
        title: project.title,
        compRate: project.compRate
      });
    },
    delProject: (state, id) => {
      state.projects.forEach(e => {
        if (id === e.id) {
          state.projects.splice(state.projects.indexOf(e), 1);
        }
      });
    },
    newName: (state, name) => {
      state.projectname = name;
    },
    newRoute: state => {
      state.reloaded++;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    newProject: ({ commit, state }, project) => {
      commit("newProject", {
        id: state.globalid,
        title: project.title,
        compRate: project.compRate
      });
      state.globalid++;
    },
    delProject: ({ commit }, id) => {
      commit("delProject", id);
    },
    newRoute: ({ commit }) => {
      commit("newRoute");
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getProjectNumber(state) {
      return state.projects.length;
    },
    getReloaded(state) {
      return state.reloaded;
    }
  }
});
```

My main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

import storePlugin from "./storePlugin";
Vue.use(storePlugin);

import componentPlugin from "./componentPlugin.js";
Vue.use(componentPlugin);

import "./registerServiceWorker.js";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router.js";
import store from "./store.js";

import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

The storePlugin is just to make the store global

storePlugin:

```
import store from "./store";
export default {
  store,
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$myStore = store;
  }
};
```

I am using Vue v2.5.17 and vue-router 2.0.
If you need more information, just ask but im pretty sure that this is all that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
import storePlugin from "./storePlugin";
Vue.use(storePlugin);
```

in main.js your Vue instance doesn't know about the **componentPlugin** and what it does because it's called after **storePlugin** (in **storePlugin** you import the store so there is where I suspect you get the **ReferenceError**)

Try this:

> main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

import componentPlugin from "./componentPlugin.js";
Vue.use(componentPlugin);

import storePlugin from "./storePlugin";
Vue.use(storePlugin);

import "./registerServiceWorker.js";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router.js";
import store from "./store.js";

import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

> store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    projects: [{ id: 0, title: "Create new Project", compRate: 0 }],
    globalid: 1,
    projectname: "",
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/home",
        name: "home",
        component: Vue.component('Home')
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        name: "about",
        component: Vue.component('About')
      },
      {
        path: "/menu",
        name: "menu",
        component: Vue.component('Menu')
      }
    ],
    reloaded: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    newProject: (state, project) => {
      state.projects.push({
        id: project.id,
        title: project.title,
        compRate: project.compRate
      });
    },
    delProject: (state, id) => {
      state.projects.forEach(e => {
        if (id === e.id) {
          state.projects.splice(state.projects.indexOf(e), 1);
        }
      });
    },
    newName: (state, name) => {
      state.projectname = name;
    },
    newRoute: state => {
      state.reloaded++;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    newProject: ({ commit, state }, project) => {
      commit("newProject", {
        id: state.globalid,
        title: project.title,
        compRate: project.compRate
      });
      state.globalid++;
    },
    delProject: ({ commit }, id) => {
      commit("delProject", id);
    },
    newRoute: ({ commit }) => {
      commit("newRoute");
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getProjectNumber(state) {
      return state.projects.length;
    },
    getReloaded(state) {
      return state.reloaded;
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to use the router in vuex I recommend [vuex-router-sync](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync)